# Can't email GSuite users from my email server

Tags: email, g-suite

I host the website for studio9architecture.ca.

(CentOS 7.6.1810 / qmail 1.03)

That company uses GSuite to manage email.

None of the users in that GSuite account can receive email **from any email accounts that are hosted on my server**.

Any emails sent to foo@studio9architecture.ca do not reach Google's servers. They also do not generate bounce messages.

Here is where it gets really odd.

Any email accounts on my server ***can*** email ***other*** GSuite accounts successfully.

And *aside from not receiving email from myself or any of the other clients that I host* the studio9architecture.ca GSuite users are not having issues receiving email from any other source.

ipv4.studio9architecture.com.  A  71.19.146.141


studio9architecture.com.  A  71.19.146.141


NS  1.studio9architecture.com.  A  71.19.146.141


NS  2.studio9architecture.com.  A  71.19.146.141


ipv6.studio9architecture.com.  AAAA  2605:2700:0:3:a800:ff:feb5:1022


NS  1.studio9architecture.com.  AAAA  2605:2700:0:3:a800:ff:feb5:1022


NS  .studio9architecture.com.  AAAA  2605:2700:0:3:a800:ff:feb5:1022


studio9architecture.com.  AAAA  2605:2700:0:3:a800:ff:feb5:1022


NS  2.studio9architecture.com.  A  AAA2605:2700:0:3:a800:ff:feb5:1022


mail.studio9architecture.com.  CNAME  ghs.googlehosted.com.


groups.studio9architecture.com.  CNAME  ghs.googlehosted.com.


email.studio9architecture.com.  CNAME  ghs.googlehosted.com.


www.studio9architecture.com.  CNAME  studio9architecture.com.


drive.studio9architecture.com.  CNAME  ghs.googlehosted.com.


ftp.studio9architecture.com.  CNAME  studio9architecture.com.


calendar.studio9architecture.com.  CNAME  ghs.googlehosted.com.


studio9architecture.com.  MX (0)ASPMX  .L.GOOGLE.COM.


studio9architecture.com.  MX (10)ALT4  ASPMX  .L.GOOGLE.COM.


studio9architecture.com.  MX (10)ALT3  ASPMX  .L.GOOGLE.COM.


studio9architecture.com.  MX (5)ALT2  ASPMX  .L.GOOGLE.COM.


studio9architecture.com.  MX (5)ALT1  ASPMX  .L.GOOGLE.COM.


studio9architecture.com.  NS  ns1.studio9architecture.com.


studio9architecture.com.  NS  ns2.studio9architecture.com.


_dmarc.studio9architecture.com.  TXT  v=DMARC1; p=none


studio9architecture.com.  TXT  v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all


I have even tried emailing foo@studio9architecture.com from the command line. No dice.

Comment: What (if any) error messages does your mail server record? Where does it try to deliver the email for studio9architecture.com? Because it could be that you (or especially your control panel if you use one) configured studio9architecture.com. not only as a website but also as a email  domain on your server.

Comment: You helped me track this down, and I super appreciate it.

I used to host this company's email, and each account was forwarded to a corresponding Gmail account.

I switched them to GSuite a few months ago.

It turns out that the server recently started routing emails the way it used to.

I would have thought that the DNS settings I'm using would circumvent that. I'm not sure why this started happening, but hopefully turning off the mail service for the account will prevent it from happening anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first domain you specified, studio9architecture.ca, does not appear to be a registered domain. I believe this may be a typo, as the rest of your message seems to refer to studio9architecture.com.

The domain studio9architecture.com appears to be hosted on a server running Plesk. It may be likely that the server thinks it is the email host for the domain, and therefore all email should be routed internally. To change this setting, try using these instructions from Plesk:

https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213927805-How-to-configure-a-domain-to-use-an-external-mail-server

Most specifically, this refers to the part where you disable the "Activate mail service on this domain" option.

Comment: Beautiful answer. I actually just arrived at the same conclusion thanks to the previous contributor. But thank you.